# How does one become invisible in Shadow of War: Blade of Galadriel?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-war

In *Shadow of War: Blade of Galadriel*, to upgrade the Light Bringer's Dagger, the challenge is to kill a captain with stealth, while invisible:

[image: Light Bringer's Dagger challenge]

However, it is completely unclear how to be "invisible". I have tried killing captains while hidden in bushes, aerial stealth kills, and sneaking up behind captains to kill them, but none of it seems to count as being "invisible". I also can't find anything relevant in any of the character skills, and I have unlocked them all.

**How do I become "invisible" for the purpose of completing this challenge?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to some gear that provides situational invisibility, Her version of Elven Wrath also gives invisibility.  One of her updgrades to Elven Wrath also extends that invisibility.

I used that invisibility to good effect on an otherwise particularly annoying Olog Captain.

Comment: To clear the challenge, I used Elven wrath just before making an aerial stealth kill, and this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need a cloak that makes you invisible. I believe it comes with slaughter tribe DLC through i am not entirely sure. You might want to make a different question regarding that.